# View running threads of process in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, xamarin

In Mono/Xamarin Studio, is there a way to obtain a list (either by debugging features or a built-in class) of the active threads of the process with names? I can see that there's threads being launched in my application (by outside libraries) but I want to get more information on them.

Gr.Viller

Answer (score 1):

Seems like too obvious of an answer, but there is a Threads window in the Debug pane for Xamarin Studio.

[image]

Comment: Yeah i've been rocking that one as well. I don't quite understand it though. It only shows the active thread that was running once I pause my application, and nothing else: http://puu.sh/5TLyC.png , http://puu.sh/5TLz4.png